# Роды или рода?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Когда речь идет не о процессе рождения потомства, а о генеалогии, то "род" во множественном числе будет "роды" или "рода"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как множественное число правильно: род**Ы**. Во всех значениях, кроме военного (там - рода войск). Последнее, впрочем, тоже скорее профжаргон. Просто в этом значении слово крайне редко употребляется во множественном числе, вот вояки и накрутили.
А "процесс рождения потомства" - р**О**ды, это слово не имеет единственного числа.